# Checkbox and Text not showing in same horizontal line inside WRAP widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, text, checkbox, flutter-animation

I have created 'Rememnber Password' UI in my login screen with below code which is inside Row() widget :

```
                 Wrap(
                      alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Checkbox(
                          checkColor: Colors.white,
                          value: isChecked,
                          onChanged: (bool? value) {
                            setState(() {
                              isChecked = value!;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "remember_me",
                          style: theme.textTheme.bodySmall,
                        ).tr()
                      ],
                    ),
```

But the issue is Checkbox looks good in center, but the Text to the right side of the checkbox has some space below it and it looks little up and not vertically in center.

What might be the issue or how can I make the 'Remember Me' text vertically in center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add one attribute of Wrap Widget,

```
 Wrap(
     ...      
    crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
     ...
```

Comment: thanks dear, I have done the same but inside parent Row() widget, It should be there in WRAP.. done. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code :

```
 Wrap(
  crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Checkbox(
                              checkColor: Colors.white,
                              value: isChecked,
                              onChanged: (bool? value) {
                                setState(() {
                                  isChecked = value!;
                                });
                              },
                            ),
                            Text(
                              "remember_me",
                              style: theme.textTheme.bodySmall,
                            ).tr()
                          ],
                        ),
```